# Divide an array of arrays by an array of scalars

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

If I have an array, A, with shape (n, m, o) and an array, B, with shape (n, m), is there a way to divide each array at A[n, m] by the scalar at B[n, m] without a list comprehension?

```
>>> A.shape
(4,173,1469)
>>> B.shape
(4,173)
>>> # Better way to do:
>>> np.array([[A[i, j] / B[i, j] for j in range(len(B[i]))] for i in range(len(B))])
```

The problem with a list comprehension is that it is slow, it doesn't return an array (so you have to `np.array(_)` it, which makes it even slower), it is hard to read, and the whole point of numpy was to move loops from Python to C++ or Fortran.

If A was of shape (n) and B was a scalar (of shape ( )), then this would be trivial: A / B, but this property does not scale with dimensions

```
>>> A / B
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,173,1469) (4,173)
```

I am looking for a fast way to do this (preferably not by tiling B to an array of shape (n, m, o), and preferably using native numpy tools).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right, there is a better way, I think you are getting the spirit of numpy.
The solution in your case is that you have to add a new dimension to B that consists of one entry in that dimension:
so if your A is of shape (n,m,o) your B has to be of shape (n,m,1) and then you can use the native broadcasting to get your operation "A/B" done.
You can just add that dimension to be by adding a "newaxis" to B there.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.ones(10,5,3)
B = np.ones(10,5)
Result = A/B[:,:,np.newaxis]
```

B[:,:,np.newaxis] --> this will turn B into an array of shape of (10,5,1)

Comment: You might want to try `B[..., None]` for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), the rules of broadcasting are:

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes
>   element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its
>   way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> ```
> they are equal, or
> one of them is 1
> ```

Your dimensions are n,m,o and n,m so not compatible.

The / division operator will work using broadcasting if you use:

1. o,n,m divided by n,m
2. n,m,o divided by n,m,1